# C# string filtering

Tags: c#, string, filtering

I'm quite new to programming in C# but i can't get this one figured out.

I'm reading out data from a serial connection, this is the output:

N 0.0198 0.0000 0.0000 0.00 0.0000 30300 1025.4 0

The data I need is the first column of numbers. It's probably not possible to use a substring with fixed values because it is possible the data output is negative.

The while loop in this code is to check if the data sent is complete

What is the best way to get this data filtered out?

Thanks in advance!

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();
        int charLoc = 0;
        int serialCharLoc = inComingData.IndexOf("N");

        while(!(inComingData.Contains("N")) && !(charLoc == serialCharLoc)) 
        {
            inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();              
        }

        rtbIncoming.Text = inComingData;
        serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();

        // this part is for filtering the data
        string usableData = inComingData.Substring(inComingData.IndexOf("N "), inComingData.IndexOf(" "));
        tbData.Text = usableData;
}
```

Comment: Is there always a space between entries? Can't you split by spaces?

Comment: `inComingData.Split(' ')[1]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first column of numbers"? In your example is this '0.0198'?

Comment: Split is the simpler option but you can also use indexof and substring. Just remember that the first parameter is the starting point and the second parameter is the LENGTH of the substring to extract

Comment: What is the output for you here?

Comment: There are always spaces between the numbers but not always in the same location. With the first column i mean the number 0.0198 in the example